# Bootstrap code for nice margin and 100% width

Tags: html, css

How to create an element in the Bootstrap that will normally equalize on one side (form left side) and 100% of the width on the other?

```css
.maksymalnaszerokosc {
max-width: 1170px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row maksymalnaszerokosc">
<div class="col-sm-6">text 1</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">text 2 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">nice same line text 1</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">Full width to right</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[See this image how to must work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUm2Z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must add class to that "full width to the right" column div, and then give it a `position:absolute; right:0%;` in the css,

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/ukGiye0V6Y

Hope that helps, Cheerio!

Comment: Thanks, this work good, on mobile I use @media (max-width: 979px) and do normal Bootstrap abilities to element :)